# onCreate is not called after switching back from preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

My app only has two activities: `main` and `preferences`

In the `PreferenceActivity` (or in my case `SettingsActivity`), the user can change some stuff, that affects the `MainActivity`.

This is my `SettingsActivity`:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have two issue:

1. When the user presses the `HomeButton` the main screen does not seem to call the `onCreate` so the changed preferences are not loaded in the main activity. What do I need to change, to tell android to call the `onCreate` function?
2. Since android nougat there are these "activity-change-animations", so when switching to a new activity, the new screen kind of `slides in`. But when the user presses the `HomeButton` the expected animation would be `slide out`, but it is also `slide in`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Use `onResume` rather than `onCreate`. It will get called whenever your Activity is back in the view. So pressing back, home, whatever way you enter the home activity, it'll call `onResume` and apply the changes from settings that the user entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation for the first issue:

There's a difference between `onCreate` and `onResume`

`onCreate`: Activity launched for the first time. Here is where you may initialize your stuff.
`onResume`: User returns to the activity after another activity goes to the background. (onPause is called on the other activity)

For the second issue, try this:

```
Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
```

Instead of

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

Comment: Nice seems to work thank you! Any clue about the second issue?

Comment: Nope, not sure, but maybe that animation is intended